# Help with Sobolev embeddings in the case of $m_{1}=m_{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, holder-inequality

In the book, Linear Function analysis by Hans Wilhelm Alt, in the
chapter about Sobolev embeddings, we see the following

if

\begin{align*}
{m_{1}-\frac{n}{p_{1}}\geq m_{2}-\frac{n}{p_{2}}\,,\quad\mathrm{and}\quad m_{1}\geq m_{2}\,,}\\
\end{align*}

then the embedding

\begin{align*}
W^{m_{1},p_{1}}\left(\Omega\right) & \longrightarrow W^{m_{2},p_{2}}\left(\Omega\right)\\
\end{align*}

Is continuous and exists.

He goes on to say that this is still the case when $m_{1}=m_{2}$
and that it follows from Holder's inequality.

I am really struggling to show this result and even seeing how it
follows from said inequality. So I ask for your guidance and help

thank you and kind regards!

Comment: Take $m_1=m_2=0$ for example. Then the claim is that $L^{p_1}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{p_2}(\Omega)$ when $p_1 \geq p_2$. This is straightforward if $\Omega$ is a **bounded domain** (this assumption is important). Indeed, write $f^{p_2} = f^{p_2} \times 1$ and apply Young's inequality (or Hölder's inequality) with exponents $q = p_1/p_2$ and $q'$.

Comment: I think you can put that as an answer